# ASP.NET Identity 2 table mapping

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

Test database with multiple projects.

First MVC project works ok using Identity 2. Correct tables were built, i.e. AspNetUsers, AspNetRoles, etc

Second project on same database not working and I'm confused as to why not.

Pathway is Registration.

In my `AccountController.cs`, Register method is called as expected and hits this code:

```
var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.ContactEmail, Email = model.ContactEmail };
```

Debugging with VS2015, shows user is fully populated.

Want to use standlone Identity tables so added following code which gets called correctly next (in my `IdentityModels.cs` file):

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("sp_AspNetUsers","dbo");
        }
```

Debugger shows no complaints.

Returns to next line in `Account Controller.cs` thus:

```
var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

Error says "**Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'UserName', table 'dbName.dbo.AspNetUsers**';"

Error seems self explanatory BUT:

> 1) Why is it referencing the AspNetUsers table and not the
>   sp_AspNetUsers table?
>
> 2) Debugging shows user.UserName has a value so why does it think it's
>   NULL?

New to MVC and Identity so any pointers to aid my learning would be appreciated.

---

EDIT

I've now amended the code in `IdentityModel.cs` to:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("sp_AspNetUsers");
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("sp_AspNetUsers");
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("sp_AspNetUserRoles");
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("sp_AspNetUserLogins");
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("sp_AspNetUserClaim");
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("sp_AspNetRoles");
        }
```

The error I now get is:

> Invalid column name 'Discriminator'

Can't see this column in the Identity tables anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First delete all the tables related to ASP identity or rename them so you can copy the data later on and than try to recreate the tables and if you have success than restore the old data.